# How to build draw.io to have lightbox viewer

Tags: build, lightbox, draw.io

I'm intending to build draw.io since cloning the repository and publish it to e.g. GitHub pages does not allow me to make use of the *lightbox*.
I assume that this repository only includes the client-side Java code but the lightbox is server-sided.

I want to make use of the *lightbox*, which allows making use of the [plugins](https://desk.draw.io/support/solutions/articles/16000056430) in view mode.
Instead of [draw.io/?p=ex&lightbox=1&...(explorer plugin enabled)](https://www.draw.io/?p=ex&lightbox=1&highlight=0000ff&edit=_blank&layers=1&nav=1#RtZRNc5swEIZ%2FDUfP8BG7viaEOtNxPZ36kPaUkdEGqRUsFUuA%2FPqKeglmsNMckhPaZxft6t2VvCjO240VpfqKEowX%2BrL1olsvDINgeeU%2BPemO5FPEILNactAI9voZGPpMay2hmgQSoiFdTmGKRQEpTZiwFptp2COaadZSZDAD%2B1SYOb3XktSRrpf%2ByO9AZ2rIHPjsycUQzKBSQmJzgqLEi2KLSMdV3sZgevEGXY7%2Ffb7gfSnMQkFv%2BeGwy5Lmi9zalfqTyJ%2FBOo%2FvF7zLkzA1H%2FhR24ocOmDLdVM3iGGxLiT0%2B%2FledNMoTbAvRdp7G9d%2BxxTlxlmBW87rG5KBJWhPENe7AcyBbOdC2DtI103NZmxEMDB10oQVM8G9z142HuVxC1bovFr5j%2BtwXey0XD18%2Bx1%2FT%2FVGXC3CmVoziUC68WETLSnMsBAmGenNVMQxZotYsnS%2FgKjjuyBqwnPC9okuTgKjCmubwisHGm6UsBnQ%2F8Zk3iYLRpB%2Bmtbx7qrPZ7QCd93l%2Bw3pbCLPqPnWIQ2ij5tSZ47vxT%2FfyasbJX8B), I would like to make it accessible via `mydomain.io/drawio.../?p=ex&lightbox=1&...`.
When I clone the repository I have only access to the editor vai `mydomain.io/drawio/src/main/webapp/index.html`, like the public clone on (`jgraph.github.io/drawio/src/main/webapp/index.html`).

Anyone here, who could give me some guidance to include the right features in the build?
Neither [draw.io build documentation](https://github.com/jgraph/drawio/wiki/Building) nor [Embed Diagrams](https://github.com/jgraph/drawio/wiki/Embed-Diagrams) tell anything about such details.
I find some more details on the [mxgraph repository](https://github.com/jgraph/mxgraph), [Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/drawioapp/posts/building-and-deploying-drawio-from-githubweve-a-long-yet-exciting-video-showing-/279482612161416/) and [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QvYZO0h1j20) but nothing gives me the slightest clue how to continue.

Answer (score 2):

You need to clone the [drawio](https://github.com/jgraph/drawio) repository from Github and launch a webserver from the directory [drawio/src/main/webapp/](https://github.com/jgraph/drawio/tree/master/src/main/webapp). E.g. for testing you can run `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` on your local machine.

Now, a local version of the draw.io/diagrams.net editor is available at `http://localhost:8000/`. The lightbox viewer you are looking for can be used via urls with this structure: `http://localhost:8000/?lightbox=1&p=ex&#R7V3rc...` (note the URL parameters and the encoded diagram within the URL).